# Android using drawable-[ANY]dpi. is it possible?

Tags: android

I'm developing android application.
I have well measured Images for "LG G3"(538dpi).
so I have to resize this images for xxhdpi(480), xxxhdpi(640). but scaling up size is very hard work. can I use these image without resizing? and Compatible with android 2.3?

Like,

```
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-538dpi
```

Or is there any way supporting "LG G3"(538dpi) with my images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets for LG G3 should go in `drawable-xxxhdpi`, or `drawable-640dpi`, but only if you wish to add super high-resolution images. Google recommends sticking with xxhdpi and letting the system scale them to the proper size for you (although for detailed images or your launcher icon, I'd personally provide the proper resolution).

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/d5opg5 . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by using the `sw(smallestWidth)` [configuration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) of the folder to specify the size/dpi you are targeting

**sample:**

```
drawable-sw538dp //for 538 dpi phone
```

Comment: It's not I wanted.. this option is checking "Device's Width in dp", Not "Screen pixel density".

Comment: @Cinakyn you know that LG G3 is 640dpi not 538dpi, so xxxhdpi is the folder you are looking

Answer (score 0):

You can generate them with ADT, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> , select `Android Icon Set`, `Action bar and Icon Set`, and you have all the sizes